# Yii Nested Set (Yiiext). Trying to move a root node

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, nested-sets

I am using the fantastic extension by Yiiext "nested-set-behavior":
https://github.com/yiiext/nested-set-behavior

I am interested to know if anyone can let me know how to move (up or down) a root node when I am running the nested set with multiple roots.

tree example:

1. Phones (root node)
   1.1 Mobile
   1.2 Fixed
2. Cars (root node)
   2.1 Fast
   2.2 Slow
   2.3 Average
3. Planes (root node)
   3.1 Large
   3.2 Small

At the moment when I pull out the full tree and show this to the user I get the above result.

I would like to be able to move "Cars" before "Phones".

Is there any way of doing this?

I have tried:

```
    $cars        = Category::model()->findByPk($cars_id);
    $phones      = $cars->prev()->find();
    $cars->moveBefore($phones);
```

This gives me an error in the moveAfter method of the nested set behavior class.

Any one done this before?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

As the doc suggest the the prev() method returns :

`Array of Active Record objects corresponding to ....`

Therefore you have to approach this with different way e.g

```
$phones = Category::model()->findByPk($phones_id);
$cars = Category::model()->findByPk($cars_id);
$cars->moveBefore($phones);
```

Or other approach which suits your application scenario

Your code could be fixed by :

```
$cars        = Category::model()->findByPk($cars_id);
$phones      = $cars->prev()->find();

foreach($phones as $phone){
  $cars->moveBefore($phone);
}
```

which does not make sense ;)

(p.s: did not test this code)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have 3 nodes, which are the roots. 
The problem is that the methods moveAfter() and moveBefore() can not be applied to the main roots. **You are trying to move a node, relatively another node, but they are in different trees.**
If cars and phones have a common root, it will be success.

In other words, you operate with nodes in different trees, which know nothing about each other.